# How to replace Enters with '<br>' in a textarea php-posting?

Tags: php, html, file, textarea, forms

I have a textarea , with some text and some enters. but I want to write all of the text into 1 line of a file in php. with `<br>` instead of enters. How can I do that?

Comment: You will need to change the string before submitting to database. Did you print out before submit to see how it looks like and understand what to replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use [**nl2br**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or [**str_replace**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

### Example:

**Sample text**

```
<?php
  $text  = 'line1
line2
line3
line4
line5';
?>
```

**with nl2br**

```
<?php
  echo nl2br( $text );
  /**
    line1<br />
    line2<br />
    line3<br />
    line4<br />
    line5
  **/
?>
```

**with str_replace**

```
<?php
  echo str_replace( PHP_EOL, "<br />", $text );
  /**
    line1<br />line2<br />line3<br />line4<br />line5
  **/
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use [nl2br](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) if you are trying to replace all the newlines with `<br>`.